# How to generate a list from a many-to-many model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class Cast(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class WorkCast(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work_Music, verbose_name=_('work'), related_name='workcast', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cast = models.ManyToManyField(Cast, verbose_name=_('cast'), related_name='workcast', blank=True)
```

I am trying to generate a list:

```
Cast member #1, cast member #2, cast member #3 from the WorkCast model:
```

I tried adding this to the model, but nothing is generated.  What is wrong?

```
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (
            self.cast,
            ", ".join(cast.name for self.cast in self.cast.set()),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a queryset of all the Cast instances you would like.

```
cast_qs = WorkCast.objects.get(id=<id>).cast.all()
```

Then, you can simply turn that QS into a list if you need to.

```
cast_qs = list(cast_qs)
```

If you only want some of the values in a list, you can call values_list on the queryset.

```
names = cast_qs.values_list('names', flat=True)
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this within a model.

Comment: @HC I guess i don't understand your questions. Are you saying you want the WorkCast String method to return show all the Cast model's names? This is possible, but not advisable. What happens when you get a cast of 100+ names?